# Curl POST with data and Node server with Express

Tags: node.js, curl, post, applescript

I'm sending a curl POST request on an AppleScript request. It sends data with the following text: "house,dog,plant". However, on my node server I just read: "house"

Any idea why? Thanks!

Applescript:

```
set testText to "house,dog,plant"

        do shell script "curl -X POST -d words=" & testText & " http://localhost:3000/comments"
```

Node server with Express:

exports.getSlideComments = function(req, res) {

```
console.log("ENTERED POST");

console.log (req.body.words); // It just prints house

res.send('200');
```

};

Comment: Did [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956648/curl-post-with-data-and-node-server-with-express/42957622#42957622) help you?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your Node program expects the data to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Try using `%2C` instead of a comma.